# Issue converting special characters to validate answers in a trivia app using API

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding

The problem is, I'm bringing in the questions for the trivia app from an API but some options have special characters. The bug is happening when the answer is equal to an option with special characters i.e. '&#039'; = '. Even when the choice is correct, it still validates to wrong.

If it helps, here is the link to my repo with the full project:
[Github Repo](https://github.com/timothyhoover/trivia-quiz)

```js
// ****************
// Evaluate Answer
// ****************
const evaluateAnswer = () => {
    checkAnswer.on('click', function () {
        // Correct Answer
        if (userChoice === undefined) {
            alert('You need to select an answer');
        } else if (userChoice == correctAnswer) {
            console.log('Correct Answer ');
            userLabel.addClass('correct');
            userLabel.append(
                '<svg class="bi check" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor"><use xlink:href="img/bootstrap-icons.svg#check"/></svg>'
            );
            $('label').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            userScore++;
            showNextBtn();
            userChoice = undefined;
            // Wrong Answer
        } else if (userChoice !== correctAnswer) {
            console.log('Wrong Answer ');
            userLabel.addClass('wrong');
            userLabel.append(
                '<svg class="bi x" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor"><use xlink:href="img/bootstrap-icons.svg#x"/></svg>'
            );
            $('label').css('pointer-events', 'none');
            showNextBtn();
            userChoice = undefined;
            // When user selects wrong answer, correct answer is also shown
            for (let i = 0; i < shuffledOptions.length; i++) {
                if ($('label').eq(i).children().text() == correctAnswer) {
                    $('label').eq(i).addClass('correct');
                    $('label')
                        .eq(i)
                        .append(
                            '<svg class="bi check" width="32" height="32" fill="currentColor"><use xlink:href="img/bootstrap-icons.svg#check"/></svg>'
                        );
                }
            }
        }

        showFinishBtn();
    });
};
```

Sample Data (with examples of special character problems)

```
{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "category": "General Knowledge",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What does the &quot;G&quot; mean in &quot;G-Man&quot;?",
            "correct_answer": "Government",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Going",
                "Ghost",
                "Geronimo"
            ]
        },
        {
            "category": "General Knowledge",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What is the name of the very first video uploaded to YouTube?",
            "correct_answer": "Me at the zoo",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "tribute",
                "carrie rides a truck",
                "Her new puppy from great grandpa vern."
            ]
        },
        {
            "category": "General Knowledge",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "Which of these companies does NOT manufacture automobiles?",
            "correct_answer": "Ducati",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Nissan",
                "GMC",
                "Fiat"
            ]
        },
        {
            "category": "General Knowledge",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What is the German word for &quot;spoon&quot;?",
            "correct_answer": "L&ouml;ffel",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Gabel",
                "Messer",
                "Essst&auml;bchen"
            ]
        },
        {
            "category": "General Knowledge",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "question": "What is the Swedish word for &quot;window&quot;?",
            "correct_answer": "F&ouml;nster",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "H&aring;l",
                "Sk&auml;rm",
                "Ruta"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you look at the screen shot attached, the label text and correct answer are the same except for the special characters, which is creating the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFbJW.png

Comment: instead of this part of the code, put a sample of the data, for example, the correct answer is "...", the user choice is: "....", 
If you are comparing strings, if they are identical then they equal each other, so there should be some difference that we need to see the data to know ;)

Comment: Hi Zac, I've added some sample data from the API so you can see the special characters issue. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Just used a encoding/decoding library to put the correct answer value into when running the evaluate answer function.

Here is the link to the library if anyone ever runs into something similar: [JS Encoding/Decoding Library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he)